# layout over riding in account page affecting category page

Tags: magento-2.1, module, layout, theme, customer-account

I am building a custom magento theme in magento 2.1. While developing I noticed that whatever change I am making to `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml` is affecting on category listing page and home page also. The changes supposed to be happen only in account sections, right? here I am attaching my `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml`file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>


    <referenceContainer name="content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container myaccount">
        <referenceContainer name="content.inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-class-4">
        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>


   <move element="sidebar.main" destination="content" before="account.content.inner"/>
    <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-xs-12 account-left"/>
    <referenceBlock name="category-sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name='customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link' remove='true'/>
     <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

</body>
```

Any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging up I could find a solution. I have removed the layout overriding codes from `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml` and added them in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml` . And everything worked perfectly alright.